# AsyncResult vs callback for getting many results from apply_async()

Tags: python, callback, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

When using the `apply_async()` method from Python's `multiprocessing.Pool`, there are two options for storing the return value - either save the `AsyncResult` object and call `.get()`, or use a callback, i.e.:

```py
# Using AsnycResult
def process_data():
    results = []
    for i in range(n):
        result = pool.apply_async(func, args)
        results.append(result)

    pool.close()
    pool.join() # Not strictly necessary, since .get() will block anyway
    data = [r.get() for r in results]
    return data
```

or

```py
# Using callback
data = []

def process_data()
    for i in range(n):
        pool.apply_async(func, args, callback=save_result)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def save_result(result):
    data.append(result)
```

Is one way more "canonical" than the other? Assuming we are submitting many (thousands) jobs to the pool, what are the advantages/disadvantages of these two approaches? The `AsyncResult` approach removes the need for a global variable, but it requires a second list (of `AsyncResult` objects) - does that effectively double the RAM required?

Comment: really just a style preference.. The callback allows you to process them "as completed", but there is a temptation to do too much processing in the callback which will block other results from the pool if that thread is busy.

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron mentioned, using a callback will allow you to process the return values from your worker function, `func`, in the order that the results are returned, which is not necessarily the order in which the tasks were submitted. Consequently, the i<sup>th</sup> element of `data` will not in general be the return value corresponding to the task created for the i<sup>th</sup> element of `args`. If you want to process results as they are returned and have the elements of `data` be in task-submission order results, then you can pre-allocate `data` to be a list of *n* `None` elements where *n* is the number of tasks being submitted. Then you must pass an an additional result index argument to your worker function, which will return the index back along with the actual result. In that way your callback knows which element of `data` needs to be updated for a given result.

What if there is a possibility of `func` raising an exception? Note that in your first method, the call to `r.get()` will raise an exception if the corresponding submitted task ended with an exception. So if such an exception is a possibility and you wanted to handle it, you would need to enclose the call to `r.get()` in a "try/catch" block:

```py
    ...
    data = []
    for r in results:
        try:
            data.append(r.get())
        except Exception as e:
            # How do you want to handle the exception?
            ...
```

To handle a possible exception in your worker function using callbacks, you would need to specify the *error_callback* argument:

```py
        ...
        pool.apply_async(func, args, callback=save_result, error_callback=handle_exception)
        ...

def handle_exception(e):
    # How do you want to handle the exception?
    ...
```